# Find the second derivative of a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

**Problem**: Find $F''(\pi)$ if 
$$
F(x) = \int_x^{\sin x}  \left(\int_0^{\sin t} (1+u^4)^{0.5} \,du\right)\,dt
$$

#### Context

I don't know how to integrate the inner part. What to do to the integral inside when differentiating? Do I have to differentiate it also?

Comment: think of fundamental theorem of calculus ($\frac{d}{dt}\int^b_t f(u)du=-f(t)$ and notice that $f(t)=\int_0^{sint} (1+u^4)^{0.5} \,du$ for some function $f$.

Comment: i dont know how to integrate the inner part. Thats why i cannot start the problem.

Comment: You have asked four question now, but you haven't shown any effort in any of the questions...

Comment: Im trying to do it. But i dont know what to do to the integral inside when differentiating? Do i have to differentiate it also?

Comment: now i understand. I can move the dy/dx inside right?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The first derivative is, using the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$F(x)=\int_x^{sinx}  \left(\int_0^{sint} (1+u^4)^{0.5} \,du\right)\,dt \\ \implies F'(x)=\cos x\int_0^{\sin (\sin x)}(1+u^4)^{1/2}du-\int_0^x(1+u^4)^{1/2}du.$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: how did you come to F'(x)?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fundamental theorem of calculus? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: Yes. but i only know how do the simple problems.

Comment: This is the same, but with more steps. To get the first derivative just consider $F(x)=\int_x^{\sin x}=\int_0^{\sin x}-\int_0^x$ and apply it. Just be confident, it is the same as in simpler cases.

Comment: i still do not get it. Sorry but what should i do with the integral o to sint of (1+u^4)^{1/2} inside

Comment: where does this cos x come from?

Comment: From the derivative of the upper limit of the integral, that is, $\sin x.$

Comment: in F'(x) i t should be (sint)^4 in the first integrand after substituition right?

Comment: In the last step, the second integral, shouldn't the limit be from 0 to sin(x)?

Comment: @Winther Typo fixed. Thank you for noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite $F(x)$ a little bit. Therefore, let $G$ be the antiderivative of $g$, i.e. $G'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$. Then, using the fund. theorem of calculus, we can write

$$
F(x) = \int_x^{\sin x}  \left(\int_0^{\sin t} (1+u^4)^{0.5} \,du\right)dt =: \int_x^{\sin x} g(t)\,dt = G(\sin x) - G(x).
$$

Now it is easier to handle:
$$F'(x) = G'(\sin x) \cdot \cos x - G'(x) = g(\sin x) \cdot \cos x -g(x)$$

and, using the product rule, we find

$$F''(x) = g'(\sin x) \cdot \cos^2 x - g(\sin x) \cdot \sin x - g'(x).$$